# How do I implement "file -s <file>" on Linux in pure Go?

Tags: linux, go

**Intent:**
Does Go have the functionality (package or otherwise) to perform a *special* file stat on Linux akin to the command `file -s <path>`

**Example:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# file /proc/uptime
/proc/uptime: empty
[root@localhost ~]# file -s /proc/uptime
/proc/uptime: ASCII text
```

**Use Case:**
I have a fileglob of files in /proc/* that I need to very quickly detect if they are *truly* empty instead of appearing to be empty.

**Using The os Package:**

*Code:*

```
result,_ := os.Stat("/proc/uptime")
fmt.Println("Name:",result.Name()," Size:",result.Size()," Mode:",int(result.Mode()))
fmt.Printf("%q",result)
```

*Result:*

```
Name: uptime  Size: 0  Mode: 292
&{"uptime" '\x00' 'Ĥ' {%!q(int64=63606896088) %!q(int32=413685520) %!q(*time.Location=&{ [] [] 0 0 <nil>})} {'\x03' %!q(uint64=4026532071) '\x01' '脤' '\x00' '\x00' '\x00' '\x00' '\x00' 'Ѐ' '\x00' {%!q(int64=1471299288) %!q(int64=413685520)} {%!q(int64=1471299288) %!q(int64=413685520)} {%!q(int64=1471299288) %!q(int64=413685520)} ['\x00' '\x00' '\x00']}}
```

**Obvious Workaround:**
There is the obvious workaround of the following. But it's a little over the top to need to call in a bash shell in order to get file stats.

```
output,_ := exec.Command("bash","-c","file -s","/proc/uptime").Output()
//parse output etc...
```

**EDIT/MY PRACTICAL USE CASE:**
Quickly determining which files are zero size without needing to read each one of them first.

```
file -s /cgroup/memory/lsf/<cluster>/*/tasks | <clean up commands> | uniq -c
6 /cgroup/memory/lsf/<cluster>/<jobid>/tasks: ASCII text
805 /cgroup/memory/lsf/<cluster>/<jobid>/tasks: empty
```

So in this case, I know that only those 6 jobs are running and the rest (805) have terminated. Reading the file works like this:

```
# cat /cgroup/memory/lsf/<cluster>/<jobid>/tasks
#
```

or

```
# cat /cgroup/memory/lsf/<cluster>/<jobid>/tasks
12352
53455
...
```

Comment: A slightly better solution: `output,_ := exec.Command("file" "-s", "/proc/uptime").Output()`.

Comment: Well, after re-reading the question several times I think we're dealing with a classical case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please could you "forget" about the `file` program for a moment and state what *initial* problem are you trying to solve? Is it about reading and interpreting the contents of `/proc/uptime` specifically?

Comment: @kostix Fair Point. My initial problem that I want to solve is that I have *files* in /proc/* that I need to quickly scan and find out if they are empty. This specific file tells me if a job still has tasks remaining for it. If none exist, the job is finished. Above when I do a `file -s <fileglob>`, I see that all of the *truly empty* files show as empty versus an ASCII Text. I'll show a practical use case that I'm trying to do in my question.

Comment: Uh, sorry, but do you mean that if you combine `path/filepath.Walk()` with `os.Stat()` the latter call returns non-zero for some files which are *truly empty?*  I'm still struggling with this "truly empty" thing because `/proc` is supposed to faithfully adhere to the conventions of a "real" file system. Isn't this the case that what you're observing is merely a regular race?  I mean, *while you scan* the entries under some `/proc` hierarchy they are free to change right under your feet: there's no guarantee of snapshot semantics or something like this.

Comment: I mean, even repeatable read of the same `/cgroup/memory/lsf/<cluster>/<jobid>/tasks` file twice in a row might bring you different results on each read (the first being non-empty with the second being empty).  Moreover, you can't event guarantee that it's impossible to have "empty then non-empty" result -- because in theory your program could have been suspended (by the OS) after the first read and in the meantime anothe job in the clusted with the same `<cluster>`+`<jobid>` was launched.

Comment: While this is improbable, certain other resources such as process PIDs are not so unique.  The kernel tries to make reusing of them be a rare occasion, but still reading something like `/proc/<pid>/status` twice in a row is not guaranteed to return you the status of *the same* process.

Comment: Oh, silly me: disregard what I said about «`/proc` is supposed to faithfully adhere to the conventions of a "real" file system»: a simple check with `stat /proc/$$/status` clearly shows that the `stat` call sees the file has size 0 while actually reading from it yelds some information. Sorry for the conusion. I'll update my answer in a moment.

Comment: Not relevant to my question but an interesting sidenote in case anyone stumbles on this; I can nearly guarantee that it is impossible to go from empty to non-empty (at least in our implementation). cgroups tracks the process IDs in this tasks file and when that file is empty the job is finished. The job is more of a meta concept collection of tasks. If there are no tasks, the job isn't running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you might be confusing matters here: `file` is special in precisely a way it "knows" a set of heuristics to carry out its tasks.

To my knowledge, Go does not have anything like this in its standard library, and I've not came across a 3rd-party package implementing a `file`-like functionality (though I invite you to search by relevant keywords on http://godoc.org)

On the other hand, Go provides full access to the syscall interface of the underlying OS so when it comes to querying the OS in a way `file` does it, there's nothing you could not do in plain Go.

So I suggest you to just fetch the source code of `file`, learn what it does in its mode turned on by the "-s" command-line option and implement that in your Go code.
We'll try to have you with specific problems doing that — should you have any.

**Update**

Looks like I've managed to grasp the OP is struggling with: a simple check:

```
$ stat -c %s /proc/$$/status && wc -c < $_
0
849
```

That is, the `stat` call on a file under `/proc` shows it has no contents but actually reading from that file returns that contents.

OK, so the solution is simple: instead of doing a call to `os.Stat()` while traversing the subtree of the filesystem one should instead merely attempt to read a single byte from the file, like in:

```
var buf [1]byte
f, err := os.Open(fname)
if err != nil {
    // do something, or maybe ignore.
    // A not existing file is OK to ignore
    // (the POSIX error code will be ENOENT)
    // because after the `path/filepath.Walk()` fetched an entry for
    // this file from its directory, the file might well have gone.
}
_, err = f.Read(buf[:])
if err != nil {
    if err == io.EOF {
        // OK, we failed to read 1 byte, so the file is empty.
    }
    // Otherwise, deal with the error
}
f.Close()
```

You might try to be more clever and first obtain the stat information
(using a call to `os.Stat()`) to see if the file is a regular file—to
not attempt reading from sockets etc.

Comment: If I'm reading the [source code](https://github.com/file/file/blob/da42d88766f4a015018d54c91dd9803b905c18ba/src/fsmagic.c) correctly, when the `-s` option is given to file it simply ignores the `stat()` call and proceeds the read the area to determine what's actually there. In this case, (and my use case) this still results in a file read call so I could potentially do something comparable.

Comment: I like the 1 byte solution as it is fairly minimalistic and may even potentially be a faster call than `os.stat()` (I'd have to test). I'm going to leave the answer un-accepted for a few days and see if any other potentials come in prior to confirming it as *the best way* forward.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a fileglob of files in /proc/* that I need to very quickly
>   detect if they are truly empty instead of appearing to be empty.

They are *truly* empty in some sense (eg. they occupy no space on file system). If you want to check whether any data can be read from them, try reading from them - that's what `file -s` does:

> `-s, --special-files`
>
> Normally, file only attempts to read and
>   determine the type of argument files which stat(2) reports are
>   ordinary files.  This prevents problems, because reading special files
>   may have peculiar consequences.  Specifying the -s option causes file
>   to also read argument files which are block or character special
>   files.  This is useful for determining the filesystem types of the
>   data in raw disk partitions, which are block special files.  This
>   option also causes file to disregard the file size as reported by
>   stat(2) since on some systems it reports a zero size for raw disk
>   partitions.